# Head Phone Transfer Function MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to model the acoustic transfer function in MATLAB for a common set of headphones? i.e. I want to model the summation of a noise sample and the audio from the output of the headphone e.g.

signal = exteriorNoise + Music

Where signal would be the information the user would hear? I would imagine headphones would implement some attenuation and low pass filtering, but I cannot find any documentation. I am aware every headphone / in-ear would be different, but I merely wish to make a more realistic model that basic signal addition.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a band-pass characteristic, since very low frequencies will be inaudible on headphones. Firstly, searching for "headphone frequency response" brings up a lot of results, especially on an image search. Then, the site [headphone.com](http://www.headphone.com) seems to offer frequency characteristic plots for many of the headphones they sell.

Unfortunately, you often only get graphs. However, you can use tools like [g3data](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php) (plot digitizing tools) to assist you in recovering data from pictures or even scans of plots. I used such tools a lot to trace plots from scientific papers for which data is usually not available.